# Can this converter chip be used for 25W power conversion?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider, multiplier

For this [LTC1043 chip](https://datasheet.octopart.com/LTC1043CSW%23TRPBF-Linear-Technology-datasheet-515827.pdf):

[image: LTC1043 Block Diagram]

Which does this:

[image: LTC1043, application circuits, divide-by-4, and multiply-by-4]

Can we deliver 1 amp of 25 volts +/- 6v (or something close to it) by dividing US-110V line voltage by 4?

And why is this chip so expensive ($5.33 in 1k qty) if it is doing something that seems fairly simple? Thanks.

Comment: What does the datasheet say about the maximum voltage and current that the chip can provide? If you want help understanding the datasheet you should provide a link to it.

Comment: are you trying to build a 25 V AC power supply? ... you could use transformer for that

Comment: I want to build the cheapest power converter possible, and I've identified switched-capacitor as a good candidate, but there don't seem to be too many good candidates, and the ones that seem possible are way too expensive for a highly competitive application. Transformer is too heavy, and too expensive.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson -- Added Link to Datasheet at your request.

Comment: Using this IC you will build a very expensive blue smoke generator. The Rds(on) is in the hundreds of Ohms (see datasheet). If you want to move 1 A over this switch, the dissipated power at the switch will hence be in the hundreds of Watts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can we deliver 1 amp of 25 volts +/- 6v (or something close to it) by
> dividing US-110V line voltage by 4?*

The [LTC1043](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1043fa.pdf) has an on-resistance of 240 ohms. That seems like a bit of a showstopper for me. Work out how much internal power dissipation there will be with 1 amp and 240 ohms.

> *And why is this chip so expensive ($5.33 in 1k qty)*

Probably because LT stuff has always attracted a higher price (even though they are now owned by ADI).

Comment: I was really looking for a Dickson Divider instead of a Dickson Multiplier. Is there such a thing? Anyway, you're right, I didn't really look at the datasheet very well, as the 240 ohm figure and 240 watt result clearly shows. Please accept my apology.

Answer (score 1):

The max supply voltage for the part is 18V, if you connected it to 110V it would explode (literally). Also you can't get very much current through the switches. There are other parts that double voltage that are much better suited for a power supply (they are called charge pumps).